# AWS DMS (source MongoDB, target PostgreSQL) need to extract info from _doc column using transformation rule, in document mode

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm running some tests of transform rules for the AWS Database Migration Service (DMS). The source database is MongoDB (I'm using AWS DocumentDB) and the target database is PostgreSQL (I'm using AWS RDS). I'm using "document mode" (as opposed to "table mode", the other option for extracting data from Mongo). In "document mode", you end up with one required column per table in the target: `_doc`, which consists of a json blob of the whole Mongo document. Optionally, you can add a `_id` column, which is a string version of the Mongo ObjectId.

I need to extract information from the `_doc` column to place into new columns in the target table (using the `add-column` action), but I can't seem to get access to the `_doc` column using the transform rules (which use SQLite functions to do the expression parsing). I *can* get access to the `_id` column, though. This discrepancy is consistent whether I try transforming each of these fields to `string`s, or to `clob`s. In the example mapping below, there are four transformations: a copy of the value of `_id` to a DMS `string`, a copy of the value of `_id` to a DMS `clob`, a copy of the value of `_doc` to a DMS `string`, and a copy of the value of `_doc` to a DMS `clob`.

(Please see AWS documentation on transform rules [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html).)

Here are the contents of the `BASIC` collection in the source db:

```
[ { _id: ObjectId("6479f558e1000ae07668a13b"), FOO: 'bar' } ]
```

Here is the DMS mapping json:

```json
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "719174426",
      "rule-name": "719174426",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_ID_AS_CLOB",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "clob"
      },
      "expression": "$_id"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "719122613",
      "rule-name": "719122613",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_ID_AS_STRING",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": "200",
        "scale": ""
      },
      "expression": "$_id"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "719057983",
      "rule-name": "719057983",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": "200",
        "scale": ""
      },
      "expression": "$_doc"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "649580464",
      "rule-name": "649580464",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_DOC_AS_CLOB",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "clob"
      },
      "expression": "$_doc"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "641760382",
      "rule-name": "641760382",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "include",
      "filters": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the schema that DMS generated for the `BASIC` table in the target db:

```
      column_name      |     data_type
-----------------------+-------------------
 _id                   | character varying
 _doc                  | text
 COPY_OF_DOC_AS_CLOB   | text
 COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING | character varying
 COPY_OF_ID_AS_STRING  | character varying
 COPY_OF_ID_AS_CLOB    | text
(6 rows)
```

And here is the resulting record in the `BASIC` table in the target db:

```
_id                   | 6479f558e1000ae07668a13b
_doc                  | { "_id" : { "$oid" : "6479f558e1000ae07668a13b" }, "FOO" : "bar" }
COPY_OF_DOC_AS_CLOB   |
COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING |
COPY_OF_ID_AS_STRING  | 6479f558e1000ae07668a13b
COPY_OF_ID_AS_CLOB    | 6479f558e1000ae07668a13b
```

I would have expected `COPY_OF_DOC_AS_CLOB` and `COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING` to show the same value as `_doc`. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `expression` field in these `transformation rules` is not correctly referencing the `_doc column`. The expression field should use a valid `SQLite expression` to reference the source column. In this case, you could try using `json_extract(_doc, '$')` as the expression to reference the entire _doc column.Modify the `transform rules`

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "719174426",
      "rule-name": "719174426",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_ID_AS_CLOB",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "clob"
      },
      "expression": "$_id"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "719122613",
      "rule-name": "719122613",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_ID_AS_STRING",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": "200",
        "scale": ""
      },
      "expression": "$_id"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "719057983",
      "rule-name": "719057983",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": "200",
        "scale": ""
      },
      "expression": "SELECT (_doc->>'_doc')::text FROM pg_temp.basic"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "649580464",
      "rule-name": "649580464",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "COPY_OF_DOC_AS_CLOB",
      "old-value": null,
      "data-type": {
        "type": "clob"
      },
      "expression": "SELECT (_doc->>'_doc')::text FROM pg_temp.basic"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "641760382",
      "rule-name": "641760382",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "include",
      "filters": []
    }
  ]
}
```

After the migration, execute the following SQL statements in the target PostgreSQL database to update the values of the COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING and COPY_OF_DOC_AS_CLOB columns:

```
UPDATE basic
SET copy_of_doc_as_string = (_doc->>'_doc')::text,
    copy_of_doc
```

**`custom transform rule`**

Consider this soln given the requirement that  you want to `extract` information from the `_doc` column in `document mode` without using the `json_extract()` function or a `post-migration` step.
Template to  extract information from the _doc column in document mode:

```
{
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-id": "719174426",
  "rule-name": "719174426",
  "rule-target": "column",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "%",
    "table-name": "%"
  },
  "rule-action": "add-column",
  "value": "COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING",
  "old-value": null,
  "data-type": {
    "type": "string",
    "length": "200",
    "scale": ""
  },
  "expression": "json_extract(_doc, '$.FOO')"
}
```

This rule would extract the `FOO field from the _doc` column and create a new column called `COPY_OF_DOC_AS_STRING`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I don't think this is an issue of SQLite syntax. If that were the case, then `"expression": "$_id"` wouldn't be correctly referencing the `_id` column, but it is.

Also, we can't do a post-migration step, because this needs to work in ongoing Change Data Capture after the initial migration.

Comment: Sorry, would change the bounty message to make the CDC thing more clear, but it looks like bounty messages are not editable.

Comment: it seems that `DMS` currently doesn't support direct access to the` _doc column` in `"document mode".` This limitation prevents you from extracting information from the _doc column to place into new columns in the target table using the transform rules. consider using` "table mode"` instead of `"document mode"` for the extraction process. In `"table mode",` DMS creates separate columns for each field in the source document, allowing you to access and manipulate the data more easily.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Do you have a link to documentation at AWS or anywhere else, stating that we can't extract information directly from the `_doc` column?

Unfortunately we can't use `table mode`. The ultimate shape of our data needs to be half way between document mode and table mode: Every top-level field needs to be a column, but below that, nested fields do not become columns -- they need to be json blobs.

Comment: could not find doc  that  can confirms  usage of   `_doc`  way u  want it but pretty much sure its the case  in `document mode, DMS` flattens the  document into a single column, called `_doc`. This means that the data in the `_doc` column is not accessible as individual fields.

Comment: custom transform rule is another op i updated the answeer

Comment: Thanks, but I actually started out using json_extract, and that didn't work. I simplified it to access _doc directly, and that didn't work either.

Comment: custom transform rule  or post processing steps . I dont see anything else. I have given the former in my answer